# How to query related object in DRF viewsets.ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, datatables, django-datatable

I have a serialised model (Job) which I am using with datatables. The "Job" model is related to another model (Board) and here is where my problem is. I followed the doc [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) to filter jobs that are related to the "Board" model which is currently being viewed, but I can't get it to work as intended.

`models.py`

```
class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('board name'), max_length=256)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('unique url'), null=True, blank=True)
...


class Job(models.Model):
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('board'))
...
```

`views.py`

```
 class JobDataTablesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Job.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted')
        serializer_class = JobDatatablesSerializer
        filter_backends = (DatatablesFilterBackend,)
        filterset_class = JobGlobalFilter
    
        def get_queryset(self):
            slug = self.kwargs['slug']
            queryset = Job.objects.filter(board__slug=slug)
            return queryset
```

`urls.py`

```
path('<slug:slug>/', views.BoardPublicView.as_view(), name='public-board')
```

Comment: The easier way to do this is by using serializer relations, https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/. this has perfectly suitable examples for your use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with a similar issue, kindly take a look at [alanjds/drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers). This is what I used and it worked perfectly.

Here is an overview of what I did.

After installing the package with `pip install drf-nested-routers`.

According to the docs,

> It is not needed to add this library in your Django project's settings.py file, as it does not contain any app, signal or model.

In my app `urls.py` file, I created parent and child routers

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'boards', views.BoardViewSet, basename="boards_api_list")

boards_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'boards', lookup='board')
boards_router.register(r'jobs', views.JobViewSet, basename='board_jobs_list')

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api/', include(boards_router.urls)),
]
```

Then in my `serializers.py`, I created a `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`

```
class BoardSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = UserSerializer()
    jobs = NestedHyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='jobs_view_name',
        parent_lookup_kwargs={'slug': 'board__slug'}
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Board
        fields = [...]
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'view_name': 'my_custom_view_name', 'lookup_field': 'slug'},
            ...other desired kwargs...
        }

class JobViewSet(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...standard serializer settings...
```

I went on to my `views.py`to  create my viewsets and added the `get_queryset` params

```
class JobViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Job.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted')
    serializer_class = JobSerializer
    filter_backends = (DatatablesFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = JobGlobalFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Job.objects.filter(board__slug=self.kwargs['board_slug'])
```

Once you do these, you should be able to access your APIs via

```
/parent_url/{{parent_pk}}/child_list/{{child_pk}}
```

Now, because of my peculiar need (I wanted to use this on datatables to filter related objects), I added the URLs of my APIs to the head of my `base.html` so that the URLs can be loaded dynamically since I can't load such in my javascript file

```
...
<head>
    <script>var boardListUrl= "{% url 'boards:boards_api_list-list' %}?format=datatables"</script>
    {% if board.slug %}
    <script>var jobListUrl= "{% url 'boards:board_jobs_list-list' board.slug %}?format=datatables"</script>
    {% endif %}
<head>
...
```

And in my `main.py` file, I did the following

```
 var table = $('#tableName').DataTable({
        ...
        "ajax": jobListUrl,
        ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the `__` for `ForeignKey` lookups. So, `get_queryset` method be like:

```
slug = models.SlugField(
    unique=True,
    default=self.slug, # This is not from the tutorial, it's a modification
    # to demonstrate here.
    max_length=13,
)

def get_queryset(self):
    slug = self.kwargs['slug']
    queryset = Job.objects.filter(board__slug=slug)
    return queryset
```

Comment: Yea, I did that, but it raises keyError["slug"]